# SqlServer - Insert multiple records and get new and old ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
CREATE TABLE [factOffertDetail](
    [idOffertRow] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [idOffertRegion] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [idProduct] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Qty] [DECIMAL](12, 2) NULL,
    [idUnitPrice] [TINYINT] NULL
    )

DECLARE @TMP2 TABLE (
    idOffertRowNEW INT,
    idOffertRow INT
    )

INSERT INTO factOffertDetail
        ( idOffertRegion ,
          idProduct ,
          Qty ,
          idUnitPrice 
            )
    OUTPUT inserted.idOffertRow INTO @TMP2(d.idOffertRowNEW)
    SELECT 
        d.idOffertRegion,
           d.idProduct ,
           d.Qty ,
           d.idUnitPrice
    FROM factOffertDetail d
```

I need to get the keys of the old and the new **idOffertRow** generated by identity.

**idOffertRow** is the identity (1,1) key of the factOffertDetail table.

How can I do this with an insert ?

Is it possible or I have to switch to merge command ?

Thanks to support

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is `idOffertRow`? it's not in your `INSERT` statement? What do you mean by the "old" ID? Please elaborate; provide DDL for your table `factOffertDetail` as well as a `INSERT` statement which we can run and what you are expecting to get back as your output.

Comment: Hi man, I have integrated the question

Comment: "integrated the question"? What does that mean? You haven't added anything I asked for apart from explained for `idOffertRow` is. What is "keys of the old"? The SQL you have above `INSERT` the values of `idOffertRow ` into your table `@TMP2`. Is this not what your after?

Comment: sorry man, now I integrate with all you need

Comment: If by "keys of the old" you mean the value of `idOffertRow` before and after an `UPDATE`, this doesn't make sense. Why are you changing the value of your `PRIMARY KEY` (on a regular basis)? When you `INSERT` a row it'll be assigned an identity; it'll keep that identity going forward even after an `UPDATE` (it's not reassigned one). If you then process an `UPDATE` statement along the lines of `UPDATE factOffertDetail SET idOffertRegion = ... WHERE idOffertRow = 10;` The value of `idOffertRow ` isn't going to change. It'll be `10` both before and after the `UPDATE`.

Comment: This procedure will run in a user business function that will be use to duplicate an offert

Comment: if it's an SP, post the whole SP; along with details of what it's doing and your goals. Provide a sample execution of that SP as well (as an `EXEC` statement`) that we can run. If your SP is referencing tables, don't forget to provide DDL for those tables, and some sample data for them as well. .It seems we're missing several parts of the puzzle here, and have a language barrier, so we need as much detail as possible so that the users here have a chance of helping you. Thanks.

Comment: `MERGE ... OUTPUT src.id, INSERTED.ID ...`

Comment: I think that MERGE is the only way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to doing this:

Alter your table with new coloum,

```
ALTER TABLE [factOffertDetail]
ADD [ParentId] [INT] NULL
```

then,

```
INSERT INTO factOffertDetail
(   ParentId,
    idOffertRegion ,
    idProduct ,
    Qty ,
    idUnitPrice 
    )
OUTPUT inserted.idOffertRow,inserted.ParentId INTO @TMP2(idOffertRowNEW,idOffertRow)
SELECT 
    d.idOffertRow,
    d.idOffertRegion,
    d.idProduct ,
    d.Qty ,
    d.idUnitPrice
FROM factOffertDetail d
```

Thank You!